# Is Hanuman an avatar of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, ramayana, hanuman

I grew up watching Ramayana and Mahabharata TV series which was telecasted on Dhoordharshan channel. I vaguely remember my grandma say that Hanuman is an avatar of Shiva to help Vishnu (Ram) to destroy the evil. Is this true? Is Lord Hanuman a form of Shiva ?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/reincarnationinindianepics/home/vishnu-as-rama/shiva-as-hanuman

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Lord Hanuman is Rudra avatar of Lord Shiva as per shiva puran. Mother of Lord Hanuman Pleased Vayu devata and Lord Shiva to have son. Vayu devata gave her boon of son and Lord Shiva was asked to give son who is exactly like him. So Lord Shiva granted Anjanimata boon that his 11th Rudra will take birth as her son and Lord Hanuman born.

In hanuman chalisa

> Shankar suvan kesri Nandan
>   Tej pratap maha jag vandan

Meaning

> As a descendant of Lord Shankar, you are a comfort and pride of Shri Kesari. With the lustre of your Vast Sway, you are propitiated all over the universe.

Reference

1. [Hanuman Chalisa](http://mandir.webmauritius.com/hanumanchalisatranslation.php)

Comment: Where did you get these details? Mention the Source, which will be more helpful

Comment: I don't see any references or links in your answer. Please update your answer. Flagged for deletion.

Comment: I mentioned Hanuman chalisa which is written by Tulsidasji, is it okey?

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Hanuman is avatar of Rudra or Shankara as mentioned in [Chapter 20](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/24274/31F_Chapter_99.pdf) Satarudriya Samhita of Shiva Purana.

> एकस्मिन्समये शम्भुरद्भुतोतिकरः प्रभुः। ददर्श मोहिनीरूपं विष्णोः स हि
> वसद्गुणः॥ ३॥
>
> The virtuous Siva, who is engaged in various types of sports, once witnessed the Mohinī form of Vishnu.
>
> चक्रे स्वं क्षुभितं शम्भुः कामबाणहतो यथा। स्वं वीर्यमपातयामास
> रामकार्यार्थमीश्वरः॥ ४॥ 
>  तद्वीर्यं स्थापयामासुः पत्रे सप्तर्षयश्च
> ते। प्रेरिता मनसा तेन रामकार्यार्थमादरात्॥ ५॥ 
>  तैर्गौतमसुतायां
> तद्वीर्यं शम्भोर्महर्षिभिः। कर्णद्वारा तथाञ्जन्यां
> रामकार्यार्थमाहितम्॥ ६॥
>
> Like a person suffering from lust, Siva at the instance, the saptarsis, (the Seven sages) carried the semen of Siva, for the purpose of Šrī Rāma, with respect, over the tree leaf and inserted the same in the ear of Anjani the daughter of Gautama, through ear to her Womb.
>
> ततश्च समये तस्माद्धनूमानिति नामभाक्र। शम्भुर्जज्ञे
> कपितनुर्महाबलपराक्रमः॥७॥
>
> Then after some time, Siva appeared in the form of a monkey by name of Hanuman who was quite valorous.

However, [Chapter 8](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/25320/44f_chapter_8_2.pdf) Kedarakhanda- Maheshwara Khanda of Skanda Mahapurana mentions Hanuman as avatar of Nandi . But Nandi is again [partial avatar](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/24254/31F_Chapter_86_1.pdf) of Shiva which indirectly makes hanuman as avatar of Shiva.

> 100. Nandi, the son of Silada, who was a favourite follower of Siva, incarnated as the great monkey Hanuman for rendering assistance to
>      Visnu of unmeasured splendour.

The above difference could be due to Kalpa Bheda.

Comment: Your link of a partial avatar does not work anymore, please update.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu use hinduscriptures.in or hinduscriptures.com. They are planning to move from .in to .com and i will update the link when they completely move to .com

Comment: Which scriptures, chapter and verse number are you referring to? Then I can manually search it.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/24254/31F_Chapter_86_1.pdf

Comment: This link is not authentic he is not a avatar of shiva.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Link is Authentic. Go to Hinduscriptures website and check. Url might be changed. Shiva's Veerya was given to Vaayu and an apsara (ap = water; sara = essence; which means whose essence is Jala tattva) was born as Anjana and she gave birth to Hanuman. Even Mantra Sastras support Hanuman is Rudra Avatara.

Comment: Shiva purana is tamasic

Comment: @PrasannaR This has been refuted multiple times on site. Same Padma purana mentions different Puranas as different body parts of Lord Vishnu. If some Puranas are Tamasic, then some body parts of Vishnu should be Tamasic. Anyways comments are not for debates, we can discuss in chat if you want.

Answer (score 4):

As far as Valmiki Ramayana is concerned Hanuman is son of Wind god. There is absolutely no mention of Hanuman being Siva amsa or Avatara. Even Uttara khanda of Valmiki indicates Hanuman as son of wind god only. Infact Valmiki Ramayana reinforces that Hanuman is avatara of wind god only.

Shiva Purana does refer to Hanuman as avatara of Shiva.

The  famous tamil Ramayana i.e.  Kamba Ramayana of 9 th century A.D. says that Hanuman was son of Wind god (Vayu) who intially invested his energy in Hanuman. Later, Siva also invested his energy in Hanuman.

Answer (score 4):

No Hanuman is not an avatar of Lord Shiva. 
Hanuman is an incarnation of Vayu .There are many references from the scriptures.One such example:

> अतो रोचननामासौ मरुदंशः प्रकीर्तितः रामावतारे हनुमान्रामकार्यार्थसाधकः
>   ।
>
> स एव भीमसेनस्तु जातो भूम्यां महाबलः ॥ Garuda Purana 3.16.68 ॥
>
> When Lord Rama incarnated on Earth, Vayu was born as Hanuman for
>   rendering assistance to Rama.

There is also a popular shloka on Hanuman which is :

> Manojavam marutulya vegam jitendriyam buddhimatam varishtham
>
> ***Vatatmajam*** vanar uth mukhram Sri Ramdootam shirisa Namami.

Here vatatmajam =vatatma[vayu]+jam[born].
Vatatmajam means vayu was born (abhivyakth) as hanuman

Comment: They probably meant in the sense of a godfather.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Yes, Sri Hanuman is considered an incarnation of Lord Shiva or Rudra both in the Tantra and the Vaishnava tradition. The mantra on the above yantra describes Hanuman as '**Rudraatmaka**' ie an Incarnation of Lord Rudra.

According to SriVaishnava-Matabja-bhaskara(82)

> In the chaturdashi tithi of krishna paksha of the month of Kartika, **Lord Shiva appeared as Kapisvara Hanuman**.On that day, the devotees should celebrate the birthday of Sri Hanuman with vows and festivals.

So the ShriVaishnavas also worship Sri Hanuman as incarnation of Lord Shiva.

**He has powered by of both Vayu and Rudra and there is no contradiction in it.Devi while killing Mahisaasura was powered by ALL the Devas.**

Comment: Is there an online reference for (the original verse and) the quoted translation that you have used here? If so, please link to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

No he is not.

Here are the names of the 11 Rudras (None of them are called "Hanuman"):

> “Aja. Ekapada, Ahivradhna, the unvanquished Pinakin, Rita Pitrirupa,
>   the three-eyed Maheswara, Vrishakapi, Sambhu, Havana, and
>   Iswara--***these are the celebrated Rudras, eleven in number***, who are the
>   lords of all the worlds. Even these eleven high-souled ones have been
>   mentioned as a hundred in the Satarudra (of the Vedas).”

**[Anusasana Parva: Section CL](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b115.htm)**

Comment: KS is right partha.. all this are fabricated Hanuman is Vayu avatar 2 kakshya above Siva..

Comment: What a terrible answer. You did not explain which avatara it is. Also your post does not add anything.

Comment: Just because i told the truth people are downvoting this answer. I gave a quote to support my argument.

Comment: If there are 19 avatars of Shiva and 11 rudra's then there can be a mismatch, right?

Comment: prove that their are 19 avatars

Comment: If God takes incarnation then they don't incarnate with same name. For example: If Vishnu takes incarnation then in his incarnated form his name will not be Vishnu, but instead he will get new name like Rama, Krishna etc. Same way, if Rudra takes incarnation then it is obvious that in his incarnation he will get new name. Vishnu also get new names in all his incarnations. This is not any proof that you are showing.