# Most of the Gods' stories end after the marriage stage. Are there any stories of Gods after their marriage?

Tags: vishnu, vedas, shiva, krishna

I heard many stories about different gods in Hinduism. A God's life also rolls in many stages as a human being like birth, love and marriage. I have a doubt that most of the God's followers didn't bother to have tales on the life of God after marriage. What is the reason behind that? Or are there any stories which are hidden from the outside world?

Comment: 3 parts of Ramayana are after Lord Rama is married and I am sure Lord Krishna's story covers his life after marriage too. Anything is specific you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking for the reason why we didn't consider so important for God's Life after their marriage. It looks similar to the climax of the film

Comment: I am sure, it isn't that way. Sage Valmiki's Ramayana I have heard, has instances how Lord Rama lived with Goddess Sita. We should get plenty of examples, like in Sundara kanda, how Goddess Sita shares a moment she has had with Lord Ram in their private time, to Lord Hanuman, during which Lord Ram applies the red tilak on her cheek than on her forehead in a playful mood, or like in Aranya kanda, its shown how Lord Rama woke up early, even though he was married and it being winter, for his daily duties.

I just heard a shorter version. The complete one and Mahabharata should help us

Comment: I am not bother about avatars of Lord Vishnu. My question is Lord Vishnu get married with Lakshmi and then?  If Vishnu has some stage like marriage in his life as human then why he didn't get old age as human ? please don't reply as "he is God" like that .

Comment: That's not correct. There are many stories of Devas after their marriages. Best example is Lord Shiva. Stories of His sons Karthikeya and Vinayaka are as famous as stories of Lord Shiva. Vishnu remarried Mahalakshmi during Sagara Madhanam in Chakvashu Manvantara. In this Vaivistara Manvantara, he took many Avatars.

Comment: The typical "kalyana" of a supreme God (such as Vishnu) is a metaphor for the union of the jeevatma (the female) with the paramatma (the male God such as Narayana). Once the jeevatma attains the paramatma, there is nothing further to be accomplished.

Comment: Can you give an example? You are relating puranic texts with movies.

Answer (score 5):

Your assumption is not correct. There are many stories of Devas after marriage.

Stories of Lord Shiva after marriage are quite famous. Stories of Ganesha  and Kartikeya are quite famous across India. Even Stories of Shiva being [born as hanuman](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16987/3500), Shiva granting [Pasupatastra](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03040.htm) to Arjuna and many such stories are famous which happened after Shiva's marriage with Parvati. People usually worship Shiva's family as whole.

Indeed, main story of Ramayana starts only after marriage of Lord Rama and Goddess Sita. Ravana [kidnapping Sita](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga49/aranya_49_frame.htm) and Rama [killing Ravana](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga108/yuddha_108_frame.htm) happened only after their marriage. Stories of Sita's exile and [Lava-Kusa](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga4/balaitrans4.htm#Verse6) are famous too.

This list is innumerable.