# Any particular god or goddess for sports?

Tags: gods

In Hinduism, do we have any particular deities for sports and other activities for the players for praying before starting playing?

Comment: Present day sports like foot ball?

Comment: whatever it may be then or now

Comment: Well if you take into consideration wrestling/kushti we normally see Lord Hanuman being the main god that is generally worshiped as Hanuman portrays strength, passion, agility and fearlessness. These are the characteristics that normally are associated with the sportsman.

Comment: Lord Hanuman! Read Hanuman Chalisa daily.

Comment: @AnuragSingh I meant amorous sport only. ;)

Comment: @Rohit.: Yeah I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

This is how wikipedia defines Sports. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sport

Sport includes all forms of competitive physical activity or games which, through casual or organised participation, aim to use, maintain or improve physical ability and skills while providing enjoyment to participants, and in some cases, entertainment for spectators.

So if the Aim is to improve physical ability and skills. Lets see which God is associated with physical ability and skills. Yes you are right He is Hanuman.

Kushti and Kabbadi are traditional sports in India, And where ever it was practiced and taught they have images for Hanuman.

Also Shiva is also very tall and powerful physically. He sits in the cold mountains, it needs enormous physical strength to do so.

As per Scriptures Hanuman is a avatar of shiva himself.

[Is Hanuman an avatar of Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8318/is-hanuman-an-avatar-of-lord-shiva)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hanuman is amsha of Shiva but they are different. You can't say they are same. They have different mantras and ways of worship.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I have never said they are same.