# Is devotion of Lord Hanuman is equal to devotion of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, hanuman, bhakti

Hanuman is the partial incarnation of Lord Shiva. So if someone is devoting Lord Hanuman then it's mean he is devoting to Lord Shiva? For example: If one being told (from aspect of kundali or any other source) that to get desired fruits you need devotion towards Lord Shiva. And he/she decides to Devote to Lord Hanuman instead (coz he feels more close to Hanuman) coz he is incarnation of Shiva.

So, will he/she get same fruit which was about to get from Lord Shiva? In other words, devoting to hanuman means devotion of Shiva or not (hope I am clear on my words)?

Comment: I think you are interpreting your dream with this logic.. Is it?

Comment: @tezz I am trying to find my ways to improve my spiritual level so that I can earn place in feet of my Lord. What's about laugh in this? Don't you have any manners? Can't you do respect of someone who is just trying to be a devotee? What I am asking is just guidance, is that too much to ask? And this time I tried my best to make question not looks like person question, Then why you laughing?

Comment: @Rishabh Please read this comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28911/how-can-all-deities-be-equal-when-the-bhagavad-gita-says-the-opposite#comment85836_28911

Comment: @Rishabh yes, what kind of savage person he is... looks like he doesn't have any manners.. but you should not care much of such useless people... such people will certainly come when you are in superior spiritual path to meet the feet of Lord.. so you should not pay much attention to these kind of people... just let bark them.. but if you are offended by such thing it might hamper your journey of purity... so be careful... I hope may you find best spritual path suitable for you.. May we all get feet of Lord..  Jay Jay Jay...

Comment: @tezz _"but if you are offended... might hamper your journey of purity"_ I have become habitual of it because people laugh at me a lot. Whoever came to know that I do too many fasts (aprox. 11 days in a month), they started making fun of me (even my own family thinks m fool). They tease me like "are u gonna take sanyasa too? u wanna be baba? why u doing this? and laugh a little in front of me and a lot on my back". I have accepted that people won't understand me but I tried to tell those person one time that they shud not laugh, later its up to them if they agree or not. I did same here.

Comment: @tezz I know people will keep laughing at me but I ignores them and keep my faith in my Lord. I know obstacles always come in journey and their laughing and teasing is also obstacle which I must overcome and keep moving forward by ignoring them. But one warning or suggest (shud not make fun) is their right which I have to give them (one time only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lord Hanuman can be worshipped as the dear servant of Lord Rama (following Tulsidasji)or as Rudratmaka(following the Ramanandi Vaishnavas) or by the Tanrik way (following Tantrasaara). Please see the answers to the question : [Is Hanuman an avatar of Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8318/is-hanuman-an-avatar-of-lord-shiva) and [Is worship of Lord Hanuman associated with Vaishnavism or Shaivism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33173/is-worship-of-lord-hanuman-associated-with-vaishnavism-or-shaivism)

The fruit of the worship depends on the perception or 'bhava' of the sadhaka, as goes the saying :

> mantre tirthe dvije **deve** daivajne vishaje gurau/ **yadrishi bhAvana yasya siddhir bhavati tAdrishi//**

Narada defines 'bhakti' as 'sA tu asmin parama-prema-rupa'. He does not mention any specific form by 'Asmin'. So Hanumanji can very well be one's chosen deity.

As Tulsidasji writes in the Hanuman-Chalisa:

> और देवता चित्त न धरई।
>   हनुमत सेइ सर्ब सुख करई।।  My mind does not like any other form.It gets all bliss from Hanumanji.

This He is saying on behalf of a common devotee of Sri Hanuman as His own Ishta was Sri Rama.

The Veera-sadhana of Hanumatdeva according to the Tantra can get anything he wants.

So I think it is the 'bhava' and devotion that are important.

The renowned saint Sri Neev Karori Baba was a Realised Soul Whose Chosen Deity was Hanumanji.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: To be honest I do not understand your answer. So the answer is no?